# I flagged this, but

Tags: discussion

For this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938965/display-data-from-database-in-a-different-ways the OP accepted an equally bad answer. I voted to close, I DV'd the question and the answer. Is my assessment of this question and answer wrong?

Comment: It looks like potential rep farming to me. I find it odd that the OP would have accepted that as an answer. In addition, both accounts are 8/9 days old. The user who gained the 15 points from the accepted answer also [promptly](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3662424/ben-craig) upvoted an answer. I find that suspicious.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't quite pass the smell test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, it's all crap. VTC, downvote, VLQ, and comment are appropriate on the question. NAA, downvote, VLQ, edit, and comment are appropriate on the answer.

I NAA'd the answer, it's gone now.

Comment: WTH? So many TLA's .

Comment: BTW this answer is GR8. TYVM.

Comment: THX M8S I EJD RITING TIS

Comment: I don't understand anything. Is this a joke?

Comment: @AnubianNoob VTC = Vote to close; VLQ = Very low quality (flag); NAA = Not an answer (flag); TLA = Three letter acronyms :)